# C++ thread from thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

Please consider this code:

```
#include <stdio>

int myInt = 10;
bool firstTime = true;

void dothings(){ 
    /*repeatedly check for myInt here*/ 
    while(true) {
        if(myInt > 200) { /*send an alert to a socket*/}
    }
}
void launchThread() { 
    if (firsttime) {
        std::thread t2(dothings); 
        t2.detach();
        firsttime = false;
    } else {
    /* update myInt with some value here*/
    }
    return;
}
int main() {

    /* sleep for 4 seconds */
    while(true) {
        std::thread t1(launchThread);
        t1.detach();
    }
}
```

I have to call `launchthread` - there is no other way around to update a value or to start the thread `t2` - this is how a third party SDK is designed.

Note that `launchThread` is exiting first. Main will keep on looping.

To my understanding, however, `dothings()` will continue to run.

My question is - can `dothings` still access the newly updated values of `myInt` after subsequent calls of `launchThread` from main?

I can't find a definite answer on google - but I believe it will - but it is not thread safe and data corruption can happen. But may be experts here can correct me. Thank you.

Comment: "I believe it will - but it is not thread safe and data corruption can happen" -- yeah, that pretty much sums It up.

Comment: As a rule of thumb : each thread can only access it's own memory, unless you're using a synchronization mecanism. Outside of that, it "may" work, but in fact, it does not.

Comment: @MartinVéronneau But globals are stored in Heap, and all threads can access heap. What bothers me really is : t2 is launched by t1 which has exited - so whether the subsequent updates to myInt will lead to a problem of variable life time. other than that what synch mechanisms are applicable here . if you could help a bit - it would be awesome

Comment: @Sean First, I'd strongly recommend pretending `detach` doesn't exist. You'll inevitably come to regret it's use outside of the most trivial use cases.

Comment: @Sean "all threads can access heap" -> They do, but without synchronization it will become a huge mess. Where each thread is launched doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Sean It's hard to say for sure if there is a problem with how `myInt` is used, as that use is not shown. What's clear is that there is a race on `firsttime`. Any number of `t1`s could be trying to read it or may have already evaluated it to be `true` by the time the first one gets to `firsttime = false;`.

Comment: I have to. there seems to be no other way to recall launchthread - the SDK forces to call launchthread (it await data on serial and when it is present it calls launchthread and detaches it automatically. I can supply a new definition of launchthread but that is it - and i cant keep launchthread running infinitely)

Comment: @Sean I'm not sure I understand the constraint, but it sounds like you're sure. But it seems like quite a terribly designed SDK, if you want my opinion. Be sure you don't have any other viable alternative, such a library may be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: sadly, that is the only one i have from the manufacturer of an external hardware, and yes i concur - it's terrible

Comment: @Sean Other than synchronizing `firstTime` (you could just use an `std::atomic` for that) it would be helpful to show what you intend to do with `myInt` if you want a constructive answer.

Comment: Some edit added. does that help?

Comment: You may wish to look at that article that is very well made : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/598695/Cplusplus11-threads-locks-and-condition-variables

Answer (score 2):

### About the lifetime of `myInt` and `firsttime`

The lifetime of both `myInt` and `firstime` will start before `main()` runs, and end after `main()` returns. Neither `launchThread` nor `doThings` manage the lifetime of any variables (except for `t2`, which is detached anyway, so it shouldn't matter).

Whether a thread was started by the main thread, or by any other thread, doesn't have any relevance. Once a thread starts, and specially when it is detached, it is basically independent: It has no relation to the other threads running in the program.

### Thou shalt not access shared memory without synchronization

But yes, you will run into problems. `myInt` is shared between multiple threads, so you have to synchronize acesses to it. If you don't, you will eventually run into undefined behavior caused by simultaneous access to shared memory. The simplest way to synchronize `myInt` is to make it into an [atomic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).

I'm assuming only one thread is running `launchThread` at each given time. Looking at your example, though, that may be not the case. If it is not, you also need to synchronize `firsttime`.

### Alternatives

However, your `myInt` looks a lot like a [Condition Variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). Maybe you want to have `doThings` be blocked until your condition (`myInt > 200`) is fulfilled. An `std::condition_variable` will help you with that. This will avoid a [busy wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) and save your processor some cycles. Some kind of event system using [Message Queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) can also help you with that, and it will even make your program cleaner and easier to maintain.

---

Following is a small example on using condition variables and atomics to synchronize your threads. I've tried to keep it simple, so there's still some improvements to be made here. I leave those to your discretion.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

std::mutex cv_m; // This mutex will be used both for myInt and cv.
std::condition_variable cv;
int myInt = 10; // myInt is already protected by the mutex, so there's not need for it to be an atomic.

std::atomic<bool> firstTime{true}; // firstTime does need to be an atomic, because it may be accessed by multiple threads, and is not protected by a mutex.

void dothings(){
    while(true) {
      // std::condition_variable only works with std::unique_lock.
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(cv_m);

      // This will do the same job of your while(myInt > 200).
      // The difference is that it will only check the condition when
      // it is notified that the value has changed.
      cv.wait(lock, [](){return myInt > 200;});

      // Note that the lock is reaquired after waking up from the wait(), so it is safe to read and modify myInt here.
      std::cout << "Alert! (" << myInt << ")\n";
      myInt -= 40; // I'm making myInt fall out of the range here. Otherwise, we would get multiple alerts after the condition (since it would be now true forever), and it wouldn't be as interesting.
    }
}

void launchThread() { 
    // Both the read and the write to firstTime need to be a single atomic operation.
    // Otherwise, two or more threads could read the value as "true", and assume this is the first time entering this function.
    if (firstTime.exchange(false)) {
      std::thread t2(dothings); 
      t2.detach();
    } else {
      {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(cv_m);
        myInt += 50;
      }
      // Value of myInt has changed. Notify all waiting threads.
      cv.notify_all();
    }
    return;
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) { // I'm making this a for loop just so I can be sure the program exits
        std::thread t1(launchThread);
        t1.detach();
    }

    // We sleep only to wait for anything to be printed. Your program has an infinite loop on main() already, so you don't have this problem.
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
}
```

#### [See it live on Coliru!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcbe17c1cc6fc241)